# Scrapy on Windows XP ImportError: No module named w3lib.html

Tags: python, windows, scrapy

I just tried installing and running scrapy on my PC at work, which runs Windows XP.

If I run scrapy startproject myproject I will get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named w3lib.html
```

Wining: It's really troublesome running Python / Scrapy on windows XP. On linux I just run pip install Scrapy and it's ok lol.

Comment: You can use pip and easy_install on Windows. Otherwise you'll have to get all the dependencies separately.

Comment: See the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows) for links to the dependencies.

Comment: I already installed all dependencies, even installed some stuff that was not in the dependies like VC 2008 c++ redistritubalt

And I could not use easy install and pip because it said my python is compiled with vc 2003 but could not find the compiler and asked me to use some other compiler..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears they forgot to list w3lib and simplejson. The latter is only required for Python versions before 2.6. Here's an installer for [Distribute](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#distribute), in case you don't have easy_install and pip. Then you can use one of the latter to get the remaining dependencies.

Comment: This was exactly what was needed! Thanks a lot, seemed kinda obvious it said it was missing w3lib :P I got easy_install working now also.

Answer (score 4):

use  `easy_install w3lib`  worked for me

Answer (score 3):

If you have pip installed, on Mac & Linux:

try:

> pip install w3lib

if you have installed it with root before:

> sudo pip install w3lib