# Installing pip using python interpreter

Tags: python, pip, scrapy, easy-install

I am reasonably new to the inner workings of Python.

I have been trying to solve the error seen here,
[Scrapy on Windows XP ImportError: No module named w3lib.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292379/scrapy-on-windows-xp-importerror-no-module-named-w3lib-html)

I installed easy_install so I could re-install Scrapy but I could not get it to do anything. I can import easy_install in, but then I expected to be able to run something like
easy_install /my_downloads/OtherPackage-3.2.1-py2.3.egg      or
easy_install http://example.com/path/to/MyPackage-1.2.3.tgz
to get one of the dependencies installed, but obviously I'm doing it wrong.

I also do not know how to get pip installed from here
http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#using-the-installer

I guess my question is how do I run commands such as below?
$ curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python

I am using the latest free enthought package and I thought either the pylab interface or the python.exe would let me run this command. I guess I am just looking for a link or rundown on how to use the interpreter an install the required packages to solve the original problem.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585875/what-is-the-official-preferred-way-to-install-pip-and-virtualenv-systemwide/32202475#32202475 for an easier way to install pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get `easy_install`, you want to install `setuptools` for windows using the executable installer provided here:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

for example, if you are running Python 2.7 on 32-bit windows, the installer would be:
`setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe`.

This will install `setuptools`, which places `easy_install.exe` in your `C:\Python27\Scripts` directory.

after it is installed, you could install pip (or *any* package from PyPI), like this:

`C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install pip`

Answer (score 0):

Start by installing Python using the [official Python installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/) for Windows. Next, download and install [setuptool for windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools) and finally [pip for windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pip).

Once you have done that, you can then install scrapy using `pip install scrapy`.